# How to see log in android for devices?

Tags: android, logging

how to see log in android for devices for the testing purpose. 
Retain log even after application not running?

Thank you

Comment: use Logs in `Service` ..

Comment: Did you mean [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)? Or just writing a log to text file manually?

Comment: how to read logcat of other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GhostLog` available on `GitHub`.

1. First down load jar file from here http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.readystatesoftware.ghostlog&a=ghostlog-integration&v=LATEST&&c=jar
2. Place jar file inside your project libs folder and add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml (inside the `<application>` tag):

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.readystatesoftware.ghostlog.integration.IntegrationReceiver" 
       android:permission="com.readystatesoftware.ghostlog.permission.READ_LOGS" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.readystatesoftware.ghostlog.integration.COMMAND" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <!--Reads logs and broadcasts them to Ghost Log-->
   <service android:name="com.readystatesoftware.ghostlog.integration.IntegrationService" />
   ```

**NOTE:** Device root (superuser) access is required to read system logs on Android 4.1 and above. 
**Non-root users can still use Ghost Log with their own apps via intent integration as mentioned above**

Comment: Is it possible to see the history of logs here somehow? Or save them to the file in an easy way?